# Add an Action to Notification to show Notification again but later, like a snooze timer for notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, action, delay

My App shows a notification. I want to add an Action to the notification via addAction that causes the notification to disappear and reappear an hour later, however I don't want to open an Activity for this, best case scenario: The user clicks the action, the notification disappears and then reappears after one hour, like a snooze timer for the notification.

Is there a way to do this without opening an activity?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

every notification action comes from a PendingIntent. For sure you don't want to launch an activity and you don't have to.

The best option on your case is to create your PendingIntent with:

```
public static PendingIntent getBroadcast (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)
```

that way, whenever the user clicks the notification, it will generate a Broadcast on the system. You then have to create a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), to receive this broadcast and schedule another PendingIntent with the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). This second pending intent will be a different broadcast, that, whenever it's fired, your BroadcastReceiver can receive and show the new Notification.

Does it make sense?

***edit:*

just to clarify into a pseudo example:

> - Your app have a BroadcastReceiver registered in the Manifest to receive Broadcasts of 'com.yourapp.mybroadcast'
> - Notification have a com.yourapp.mybroadcast PendingIntent with extras boolean isSchedule = true and int time = 60 (60 minutes)
> - The user taps the notification and this broadcast is fired and your BroadcastReceiver receives `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`
> - Inside your onReceive you read isSchedule=true (meaning it have to create a new schedule and time = 60 minutes. So it uses the
>     AlarmManager to create a new Broadcast PendingIntent with isSchedule =
>     false; to be fired in 60 min
> - The AlarmManager will call your BroadcastReceiver again in 60min but this time with isSchedule = false, so your BroadcastReceiver knows its
>     time to show the notification again.

Comment: Hey, thank you for you answer, I get the logic but can't seem to get it to work with this code: d = b.getInt("deltaMillis"); DateTime alarmTime = new DateTime(); alarmTime.plusMillis(d);
   Intent delayedI = new Intent(context, MBroadcastReceiver.class);
   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, delayedIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
   AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime.getMillis(), pi); From logcat I see that the code gets executed, however the broadcast doesnt get fired

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was in Joda Time. It doesn't seem to be exactly in sync with system time. When I use System.currentTimeMillis()+scheduleDelta as the time for the notification it works!